# Multiple joins on the same table, Results Not Returned if Join Field is NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

```
SELECT organizations_organization.code as organization,
core_user.email as Created_By,
assinees.email as Assigned_To,
from tickets_ticket 
JOIN organizations_organization on tickets_ticket.organization_id = organizations_organization.id
JOIN core_user on tickets_ticket.created_by_id  = core_user.id 
Left JOIN core_user as assinees on assinees.id = tickets_ticket.currently_assigned_to_id
```

In the above query, if tickets_ticket.currently_assigned_to_id is null then that that row from tickets_ticket  is not returned

```
> Records In tickets_ticket = 109
> Returned Records = 4 (out of 109 4 row has value for currently_assigned_to_id  rest 105 are null )
> Expected Records = 109 (with nulll set for  Assigned_To)
```

Note I am trying to achieve multiple joins on the same table

Comment: Just a note to make things clearer, the `INNER` keyword is optional. I.e. `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN can not kill output records,
your problem is here:

```
JOIN core_user on tickets_ticket.created_by_id = core_user.id
```

this join kills non-matching records
try

```
LEFT JOIN core_user on tickets_ticket.created_by_id = core_user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not the actual code you are running.  There is a comma before the `from` clause that would cause a syntax error.  If you have left out a `where` clause, then that would explain why you are seeing no rows.

When using `left join`s, conditions on the *first* table go in the `where` clause.  Conditions on subsequent tables go in the `on` clause.

That said, a `where` clause may not be the problem.  I would suggest using `left join`s from the first table onward -- along with table aliases:

```
select oo.code as organization, cu.email as Created_By, a.email as Assigned_To,
from tickets_ticket tt left join
     organizations_organization oo
     on tt.organization_id = oo.id left join
     core_user cu
     on tt.created_by_id = cu.id left join
     core_user a
     on a.id = tt.currently_assigned_to_id ;
```

I suspect that you have data in your data model that is unexpected -- perhaps bad organizations, perhaps bad `created_by_id`.  Keep all the tickets to see what is missing.

That said, you should probably be including something like `tt.id` in the result set to identify the specific ticket.